# Where is libapache2-mod-qos?

Tags: 10.10, server, repository, apache2

I wish to install [mod_qos](http://mod-qos.sourceforge.net/) in Ubuntu Server 10.10.

Reading on-line [it would seem the package is called libapache2-mod-qos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libapache2-mod-qos) and is in the Universe repository.

Having enabled Universe and performing a `sudo apt-get update` it still cannot be found, and the listing for `aptitude search libapache2` does not show it under another name.

Has it really been taken out of the repos (in desperation I temporarily enabled every repo and updated to no avail)? If not does it have an obscure name now or are we meant to use a PPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package seems to be new to the current development release, Natty:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapache2-mod-qos

To install it on 10.10, you can just download that .dsc file and build the package:

```
dget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libapache2-mod-qos_9.25-1.dsc
```

Then extract it

```
dpkg-source -x libapache2-mod-qos_9.25-1.dsc
```

Then build it

```
cd libapache2-mod-qos-9.25
debuild
sudo debi
```

If this works, consider submitting it as a backport to 10.10:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports#How to request new packages

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a PPA but did locate the packages [HERE](http://pixie.sd.chgo.fastservers.net/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libapache2-mod-qos/).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just added the natty universe repository to the system (this will come back to bite at a future date as it included base without consent) and it seemed to work fine for this test development machine. However @SpamapS answer would seem to be "the right thing" to do.